# Cutting value in vector by determine positions

Tags: r, vector

Is there a function in R that I can cut a value in vector.

for example i got this vec:

```
40754831597
64278107602
64212163451
```

and each vale in the vec i want to cut so from the number pos 3 to 6 for example and get a new vector look like this

```
7548
2781
2121
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why you would like to do this, but here you go:

```
# assuming it's a character vector
substring(vec,3,6)

# if it's numeric
substring(as.character(vec),3,6)

#output
#[1] "7548" "2781" "2121"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
sub(".{2}(.{4}).*", "\\1", v1)
#[1] "7548" "2781" "2121"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(40754831597, 64278107602, 64212163451)
```